# Xcode Error: Showing Recent Messages tried to merge string value for key 'CFBundleExecutable' onto dictionary value

Tags: xcode, dictionary

While making a project in Xcode, I ran into the error "*tried to merge string value for key 'CFBundleExecutable' onto dictionary value*." As an additional message to this error, the compiler states: "*tried to merge string value for key 'CFBundleExecutable' onto dictionary value*." I am wondering what the error could possibly be, and how can I fix this? I appreciate the help!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide sample code with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise it's going to be very hard for the others to help.

Answer (score 0):

1.This error occurs when you are trying to merge a string value with an array value for the key "CFBundleIdentifier". To resolve this issue, you should make sure that both values are of the same data type. If you want to append the string value to the array, you can use the append method: